# MacBook Pro takes longer time to open some apps while connected to wifi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I am using a 2017 None Touch Bar MacBook Pro. It's running on MacOs Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101). I have noticed many times that when I try to open some apps like Chrome, IINA player etc, while connected to WiFi, it takes a lots of time. But as soon as I turn off WiFi, they start immediately. Also when I try to open those without connecting to wifi, they also start immediately. Anyone have experiencing this scenario.

My WiFi connectivity is 3Ghz IPV4 and It does not have any issue with my other connected devices like iPhone.

Comment: Can you get a screenrecording to show what's happening?

Comment: @JashJacob the app just bounces eternally in the dock and the moment you disconnect wifi, it stops and launches.

Comment: @anki yes, thats is what exactly happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with macOS Catalina, macOS now automatically sends the signature of every executable you open to Apple. Obviously, if you don't have an internet connection, it won't check with Apple's servers. When you do have an internet connection, it must send the signature to Apple's servers, then wait for the response. This is made worse by slower internet.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I think thats what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Some apps ping their own servers, so it takes some time. Sometimes gatekeeper decides to check something by connecting to Apple servers. Using firewall helped speedup the launch time of some apps. But some apps just delay the launch sometimes anyway.

- [Does macOS phone home to Apple's servers before running an app for the first time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391379/does-macos-phone-home-to-apples-servers-before-running-an-app-for-the-first-tim)
- [How to stop Catalina from contacting Apple servers when executing programs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393689/how-to-stop-catalina-from-contacting-apple-servers-when-executing-programs?noredirect=1&lq=1)