# Apps & files slow to open in my MacBook Air, and it seems like it's trying to do some security check online?

Tags: macos

Unless I'm online or the Wi-Fi is disabled, apps & files usually take a long time to open. As soon as I'm back online, or I disable the Wi-Fi, everything starts acting snappy again. What could be the cause?

Comment: I would get [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)  to verify those observations.

Comment: See this possible dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391399/119271

Comment: What OS version?